# Another Unconfirmed BTC transaction

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

Sorry guys & gals - yet another "unconfirmed BTC transaction..".

Looks like the fee was too small, but this was sent 72 hours ago now (at the time of writing)

https://blockchain.info/tx/f81760ebe76ad0e64374ee3d243f0549fe809d61285c5631c01def84848dcdb2

Do I just need to be more patient?

Edit:12/06/16 - It has been over 120 hours now, are there any options for me to retract the transfer and re-submit with a higher fee?

Comment: First of all tell me which bitcoin wallet you are using to store and make transactions ? It is showing the size of transactions too high than expected. But don't worry, be a patient person, it will be confirmed soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes be more patient. In the future you can use this app or others like it to determine an appropriate fee for faster confirmation:

https://bitcoinfees.21.co/

"Which fee should I use?

The fastest and cheapest transaction fee is currently 50 satoshis/byte, shown in green at the top.
For the median transaction size of 226 bytes, this results in a fee of 11,300 satoshis (0.04$).

What are the fees shown here?

The fees displayed here are Satoshis (0.00000001 BTC) per byte of transaction data. Miners usually include transactions with the highest fee/byte first. 
Wallets should base their fee calculations on this number, depending on how fast the user needs confirmations."